# Emacs indenting after macro in C

Tags: c, emacs, macros, auto-indent

```
#define INIT_MACRO create(); some(); enviroment();
...
void function(){
  INIT_MACRO
    extra_indented();
  normal_indented();
}
```

how do i make emacs deal correctly with the above situation when it is requested to automatically indent?

EDIT the only solution i see is to tell emacs to treat lines containing only caps, underscores and spaces as if they have a semicolon at the end... but how would i do that?

Comment: I don't think this is doable. You could remove the last `;` and add it to the macro itself. This won't fool emacs indentation.

Comment: Why a macro and not a function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
#define INIT_MACRO do { create(); some(); enviroment(); } while (0)
...
void function(){
  INIT_MACRO;
  extra_indented();
  normal_indented();
}
```

It is usually better to use this trick to avoid problems when you use:

```
if (...)
  MACRO();
else
  ...
```

and a semicolon on each line is easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: This is the way i got along so far but i would not feel comfortable changing code in the repository at will because my indentation breaks... (see EDIT)

Comment: As I told you, for me it is not only for indentation sake but for security and readability too.

Comment: valid point, but i still would love it if i could just do what i suggest in the edit in some occasions

Answer (score 4):

`cc-mode` has this customizable via `c-macro-names-with-semicolon` variable. See the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Macros-with-_003b.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just end the INIT_MACRO line with a ;?

Answer (score 0):

Using a macro as function wrapper without `();` at the end when you call it and without surrounding the define with `do {` and `} while(0)` is not done anyway.. makes the code ugly, hard to maintain and it's not supported by one C coding standard... with other words it's called bleeding eye code. So it is not possible with the default settings.

You would need to make your own major / minor mode. To support this new type of syntax... Or you could have a look at your current cc-mode.el.